# An equation and a function and visualizing it

Tags: functions

Following equation have two real variables $x$ and $y$:

$$\left( x-1\right)^{2}  +y^{2}=1$$

The solution set to the equation is $G$.

a) Formulate the set $G$ and draw its graph.

$$G = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R} \mid (x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1\}$$

Is it correct?

We also know it's a circle, with radius $1$, centre at $x = 1$, $y = 0$.

b) Formulate a function whose graph partially coincides with the graph of $G$. Draw the graph of that function.

I'm not sure about this one.

c) How many functions, whose graph partially coincides with the graph $G$, exist?

I was told that there is an infinite number of functions whose graph partially coincides with the graph of $G$, but I'm not sure how to explain why.

Comment: I would interpret “partially coincides” as “intersects in one or more places”. Hopefully you can take it from there?

Comment: Is the answer for a) correct?

Comment: "The solution set to the equation is "  means $G= \{$every possible values were the equation is true$\}=\{$ all possible $x,y$ where $(x-1)^2 + y^2$ *DOES* equal $1\}=\{(x,y)|x\in R, y\in R, (x-1)^2+y^2 = 1\}$ or a another way of putting it is $G = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2| (x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1\}$.  The only errors in your statement are a) you didn't put it in set notation (although that is probably a MathJax error: write "\{...\}" to make the brackets appear) and b)  $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$.  $(x,y)\not \in \mathbb R^2$.  $(x,y)$ is a *pair* or real numbers; not a real number itself.

Comment: "formulate a function whose graph *partially* coincides with the graph of . Draw the graph of that function.

I'm not sure about this one."  Notice that $G$ is a circle.  Can a circle ever be a function? Why or why not? (hint: Vertical line test?  Also what is the domain of a function?  What if $x<0? What if $x > 2$?)  But can *PART* of a circle be *PART* of a function?  If so describe the function.... (Actually, IMO this is a badly written question the are lots of *parts* of the circle that can be *part* of a function that the question is too open-ended.)

Comment: c)  I suppose it might be a bit of a spoiler to just tell you the answer is "infinite".  $(1,1)$ is part of the solution.  $(1,1)$ is a point on the function $y=f(x) =x$.  $(2,0)$ is part of the solution.  $(2,0)$ is a point on the function $y=g(x) = x^3-2x-4$.  .... I could go on all day.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to the first part of the question is correct.

[image: graph of circle (x - 1)^2 + y^2 = 1]

As Mufasa pointed out in the comments, any function whose graph intersects the circle partially coincides with the graph of $G$.

Since you were asked to graph such a function, perhaps the person who posed the question wanted you to work with the equation
$$(x - 1)^2 + y^2 = 1$$
Solving for $y$ yields
\begin{align*}
y^2 & = 1 - (x - 1)^2\\
|y| & = \sqrt{1 - (x - 1)^2} && \text{(take the square root of each side of the equation)}\\
y & = \pm \sqrt{1 - (x - 1)^2}
\end{align*}
If we want $y$ to be a function, we can only have one $y$-value for each $x$-value, so we have to make a choice.  If we set
$$y = \sqrt{1 - (x - 1)^2}$$
then we obtain those points $(x, y)$ of the circle $(x - 1)^2 + y^2 = 1$ such that $y \geq 0$, that is, the upper half of the circle.  Since $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, one possible function that coincides with part of the graph of the circle $(x - 1)^2 + y^2 = 1$ is the function $f: [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $y = \sqrt{1 - (x - 1)^2}$.

[image: graph of the function y = sqrt[1 - (x - 1)^2]]

Since any function whose graph intersects the circle partially coincides with its graph, there are infinitely many such functions.  For instance, there are infinitely many lines which pass through the origin that intersect the graph since the line $y = mx$ intersects the circle $(x - 1)^2 + y^2 = 1$ if $m$ is any real number satisfying $-1 \leq m \leq 1$.

Even if we restrict our attention to functions that include the upper half circle $y = \sqrt{1 - (x - 1)^2}$ in their graph, there are still infinitely many since we can assign any rule we like on the intervals $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$ to extend the domain of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  For instance, we could define $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as follows:
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}
         \sqrt{1 - (x - 1)^2} && \text{if $0 \le x \le 2$};\\
         0 && \text{otherwise}
         \end{cases}
$$
The rules on the interval $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(2, \infty)$ need not be the same.  For instance, we could define $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as follows:
$$h(x) = \begin{cases}
         -x && \text{if $x < 0$}\\
         \sqrt{1 - (x - 1)^2} && \text{if $0 \le x \le 2$};\\
         x - 2 && \text{if $x > 2$}
         \end{cases}
$$

Answer (score -1):

[image: Question a]

We can see the four points of the circle that when x=1 y=0, so it is true.